# Format a string into Date or any other datatype in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, date, salesforce

I am using Python 3.6 with Django 1.11. My Back-end DB is Salesforce.

I am trying to save date field in Salesforce which is accepted from user in the form of String

```
str_var = '11/09/2017'
```

want it to be converted like `not_a_str_var = 11/09/2017`

I tried with several datetime, date functions but no success.
I have also tried using strptime() and strftime() methods.

I pass values to Salesforce from django using simple-salesforce REST API.
Expected insert statement is

```
dataToSFDC = [{'Birthdate': 11/09/2017, 'FirstName': 'testfname', 'LastName': 'testlname', 'Email': 'test@gmail.com','AccountId': '0011F0000043u7fQAA'}]

sf1 = salesforceConnection()

sf2 = sf1.bulk.Contact.insert(dataToSFDC )
```

Please suggest

Comment: Could you try do not use bulk? `sf1.Contact.create({'Birthdate': '2000-01-01', 'FirstName': 'testfname', 'LastName': 'testlname', 'Email': 'test@gmail.com','AccountId': '0011F0000043u7fQAA'})`

Comment: @Alexey Single contact is created successfully with Birthdate. 
My issue with bulk contact still exist

Comment: Do you know why Date is not supported for bulk insert?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea yet. In both cases simple-salesforce uses `json.dumps()` before sending data to API

Comment: ok, no problem, will try to figure out something. Thanks for the help!

Comment: After all the trials, finally I broke down bulk insert into single insert & worked my way out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [link](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce#record-management), one should pass dates as UTC datetime, so:

```
import pytz
from datetime import datetime

d = datetime.strptime('11/09/2017', '%m/%d/%Y')
dataToSFDC = [{'Birthdate': pytz.utc.localize(d).isoformat()}]
```

Edited: there was a typo: pytz.utc.**localize**

Edited 2: [salesforce dates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Data-Loader-Import-data-for-Date-or-Date-Time-field-1327108684799&language=en_US&type=1) describes date formats. Hope following should help.

```
d = datetime.strptime('11/09/2017', '%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%F %T')
dataToSFDC = [{'Birthdate': d}]
```

Comment: I tried this approach but the 'UTC' object has no attribute 'localized'

Comment: After using pytz.utc.localize the data appears like this 
dataToSFDC = [{'Birthdate': datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 19, 0, 0, tzinfo=<UTC>)]
and Error thrown is: Object of type 'datetime' is not JSON serializable

Comment: My bad. For bulk insert they need json-serializable objects. Datetime should be converted into iso format: `pytz.utc.localize(d).isoformat()`

Comment: After using isoformat() the output is 
dataToSFDC = [{'Birthdate': '2017-11-09T00:00:00+00:00'}] & error is Malformed request https://cs90.salesforce.com/services/async/38.0/job/7501F0000001wLvQAI/batch/7511F00000012FhQ
AI/result. Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}

Comment: sorry for late reply. I tried with new option of strftime('%F %T') but still I get error. I think the below error is because, we pass string to date
{'Birthdate': '2017-11-04 00:00:00'} 
Malformed request https://cs90.salesforce.com/services/async/38.0/job/7501F00000027aOQAQ/batch/7511F00000015
NAQAY/result. Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}

Comment: This error could appear because the SFDC user doesn't have the access to a specific field.
For the detail you can go to SFDC -> Bulk Data Load Jobs, check the error log which will tell you which field can't access by this user.

Comment: I checked the access & its available. To add more I login as Admin while trying to insert data into SFDC.

Comment: Nothing useful in error log. I guess the issue is with Bulk loading wrt Date datatype.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way to do this would be:

```
def text_to_date(date_text):
    if not date_text:
        raise ValueError('Empty Date')
    month = int(date_text[0:2])
    day = int(date_text[3:5])
    year = int(date_text[6:10])
    date_time = datetime.date(year,month,day)
    return date_time
```

Comment: This is naive approach, also you cant pass int value to datetime.date()